# Two dimensional array to one dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a two dimensional array and I fill it with scanner. I want to copy the elements that start with letter 'a' to a new one dimensional array without using ArrayList. Please advise on what I can do to get this code functioning properly. the question is how can I know the new array size while I don't know how many words start with letter a

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Untitled {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[][] name = new String[2][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < name[i].length; j++) {

                name[i][j] = input.next();

            }

        }
        student(name);

    }

    public static void student(String[][] arr) {
        int count = 0;
        int c2 = -1;
        String[] name2 = new String[count];
        String temp = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {

                if (arr[i][j].charAt(0) == 'a') {
                    c2++;
                    temp = arr[i][j];
                    name2[c2] = temp;
                    count++;
                    temp = "";
                }

            }//inner

        }//outer

        for (int i = 0; i < name2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(name2[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the code work? Where are you stuck? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: And what question do you actually have?

Comment: I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: the question is how can I know the new array size while I don't know how many words start with letter a

Comment: Why do you think that initializing the array with size as `count` and then increasing `count` would also increase the array size? How should that work?

Comment: *"how can I know the new array size while I don't know how many words start with letter a"* - You can't and the question is: why do you even want to use an array?

Comment: You can't know how many words satisfy your condition without counting them first. Either you have to iterate twice (1. iterate to count all occurrences; 2. initialize array with count; 3. iterate again to fill in values), or use a dynamic container like `ArrayList`.

Comment: I have problem with the third point I don't know how to copy elements from tow dimensional array to one dimensional array with nested loop how to set the one dimensional array indices with nested loop

Comment: Then please state exactly what you need in your question. Right now, you're asking something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two dimensional arrray of size **[n][n]** is equal to one dimensional array of size **n**. If you want to copy them on proper place then you can use this formula, it is useful if you later want to copy these elements back to twodimensional array at proper places:

```
int v = i * n + j; // i and j your loops and n is length of rows or colums.


array[v] = array[i][j];
```

for in your codes it's like:

```
int v = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {

        if (arr[i][j].charAt(0) == 'a') {
             v = i * arra.length +j;
             name2[v] = arr[i][j]; 
                count++;
```

Ok here is a working code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] name = new String[2][2];
        System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < name[i].length; j++) {

                name[i][j] = input.next();

            }

        }
        student(name);
    }



public static void student(String[][] arr) {
        int count = 0;
        int v = 0;  
        String[] name2 = new String[arr.length*arr[0].length];
        String temp = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {

                if (arr[i][j].charAt(0) == 'a') {
                    v = i *+arr[0].length + j;
                    name2[v] = arr[i][j];
                    count++;
                }

            }//inner

        }//outer

        for (int i = 0; i < name2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(name2[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("printing without nulls");
        //if you don't want null to be printed then do this:
        for (int i = 0; i < name2.length; i++) {
            if(name2[i] != null)
            System.out.println(name2[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks can you do this with my codes it doesn't work when I try it

Comment: what do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: and is there a way to fill the one dimensional array with the elements that start with letter 'a' for example if I have 2 word in the two dimensional array starting with letter 'a' the one dimensional array size would be 2

Comment: It's the conversion of your two dimensional array to one dimension.You can think its a formula for conversion an try to plug in values and you will see how you get result.

Comment: To make the size exact you first have to count how many elemnts you have in two dimensional array starting with a. then create an arrray of exact size n where n is number of letters starting with a.

Comment: thanks can you check the code below, is it the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I did it with two nested for loop one for indicating the array size and the other for filling the elements into the array, it does the work but is there any way to do this better

```
public static void student(String[][] arr) {
    int size = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {


            if (arr[i][j].charAt(0) == 'a') {
                size++;
            }

        }//inner

    }//outer
    String[] name2 = new String[size];


    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {


            if (arr[i][j].charAt(0) == 'a') {
                name2[count] = arr[i][j];
                count++;
            }

        }//inner

    }//outer

    for (int i = 0; i < name2.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(name2[i]);
    }
```

Comment: In java arrays can't change side that's why java has arraylist and it's good.